# Populating a drop down list with c# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I am trying to populate a drop down list using code behind (C#).  I am not sure how to get this. Below is my code that I am currently trying to use but I am getting errors.  I am trying to populate a drop down list the stores the months ( 1 - 12).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  for (int i = 0;  i < 12; i++)
    {

        DropDownListMonth.SelectedValue = i;
        DropDownListMonth.DataTextField = i.ToString();
        DropDownListMonth.DataValueField = i.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: What errors you get on this code?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you just need to add items in your dropdownlist. How about using [`List<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) with [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) loop like;

```
List<int> months = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
foreach (string month in months)
{
     DropDownListMonth.Items.Add(month);
}
```

Because your for loop works `0` to `11` not `1` to `12`. And it is not adding any item. It just sets [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`DataTextField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`DataValueField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as `11`, doesn't do anything more.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need to do

```
for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++)
{
    var item = new ListItem
        {
            Text = i.ToString(),
            Value = i.ToString()
        };
    DropDownListMonth.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a list, add the values to that list, and have that list bound to the dropdown.

Also, have a look at this article to clear up some confusion: [selected item, value, and more](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671544/Understanding-SelectedValue-SelectedValuePath-Sele)